# Laravel5: refresh method for eloquent models?

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, refresh

I create a model and save it, using the save() methods, and I do not fill all properties. Mysql will set the assigned default values of the columns.

But the values are not filled after, just the primary keys.

Isn't there a something like "refresh()" method which updates my model instance with the actual data?

Comment: can you please show the code here?

Answer (score 3):

1. **Yes**. There's a `fresh` method on the model that does exactly that.
2. You shouldn't need this. You should add the default values to the `$attributes` array so that you always have the default values automatically.

Comment: What if you have default values on the column schema?

Comment: @atomkirk - there;s currently no way in Laravel to automatically handle those. You'd have to add the default values to the `$attributes` array, same as if they weren't in the schema.

Comment: Also fresh() loads a new instance, it doesn't refresh fields in current model instance if they have changed outside of the current model

Comment: @madz - by now, Laravel also has a `refresh()` method that _does_ refresh the fields on the current model.